# como obter as coordendas Polygon de uma cidade em python?

Tags: python

Boas, para obter as coordenadas(lat,long) de uma cidade consigo utilizando geolocator.geocode, mas preciso obter as coordenadas polygon(toda a área da cidade), alguém sabe de uma outra biblioteca que me retorne as coordenadas Polygon da cidade?

Este exemplo diz respeito à cidade Arrecife
[image]

usando  geolocator.geocode, só me dá info da latitude e longitude.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma, evitando maiores frustrações.

Comment: Acredito que você possa usar o [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) ou [Radar](https://radar.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a biblioteca geopandas, baixe o shapefile do Brasil ou do estado em questão pode ser aqui [NEREUS](http://www.usp.br/nereus/?dados=brasil) e seguida abra o arquivo .shp

```
br = gpd.read_file('gadm36_BRA_1.shp')
```

Você obterá um geoDataFrame:
[image: geodataframe]

Como pode ver na coluna geometry tem os polygons e multipoligos.

Obs: baixe um shapefile que tenha todas as cidades e filtre a que você deseja.